# How to model variable swap in SMT (Z3)?

Tags: z3, smt, formal-verification

I have a program that sorts variables, and I'm trying to check its validity with Z3, but I have one code segment where the variables are being swapped and I don't know how to model it in SMT syntax. Here is the original code segment:

```
if (x > y) {
  temp = x;
  x = y;
  y = temp;
}
```

And regarding the SMT I have written an assertion, but I guess it is not exactly the correct thing:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun temp () Int)

(assert (=> (> s1 s2) (and (= tmp s1) (= s1 s2) (= s2 tmp))))
```

Any ideas how to do variable assignment in SMT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into Single Static Assignment [1]. In this way you can rewrite your original code as follows.

```
if (x0 > y0) {
  temp0 = x0;
  x1 = y0;
  y1 = temp0;
}
```

It thus becomes clear that you have two different instances of x and y. The first (x0, y0) is the one you are comparing in the if condition. The second (x1, y1) is the result of the operation.

This introduces an implicit notion of time that makes it also easier to write properties about your code. E.g.,

```
  ((x1 = x0) & (y1 = y0)) | ((x1 = y0) | (y1 = x0))
```

Of course, this might require adjusting other parts of your code, so that you are using the right variables.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite what you want using a single expression as a tuple:

```
(result1, result2) = x > y ? (x, y) : (y, x)
```

Z3 supports tuples but I'm less experienced with that. It's probably easier to blast this into parts:

```
result1 = x > y ? x : y
result2 = x > y ? y : x
```

And the `?:` operator maps to `ITE` in Z3.

You don't even need "temp variables" for this (but clearly you *can*).

> (assert (=> (> s1 s2) (and (= tmp s1) (= s1 s2) (= s2 tmp))))

I think this is revealing that you don't understand that Z3 "variables" are actually constants and you cannot actually swap them. In each model they take on a single value only. There is no temporal component to constants. `=` means "is equal?" and not "make it equal!".

Comment: Yes, but how can I use `ite` for assignment, I mean in `ite` I can do something like `(ite (< x y) x y)`, but how can I ensure with this that if `x < y` then the value of result is actually `x`?

Comment: Do you understand that you cannot assign at all in Z3? Values and constants are immutable. `=` does not assign. `and` does not assign. `assert` does not assign.

Comment: Yes, I do understand, but I just don't get how I can translate the my above code segment to SMT syntax. Can you give the complete example with `ITE` as you have suggested, so that I can see what you mean. Because what you have written makes sense, but I don't see how to translate it to SMT.

Comment: Alright, the translation is straight forward. Untested: `(ite (> s1 s2) s1 s2)` as an expression for `result1` (or whatever the name). You don't need to declare a constant. You can just use this expression which usually is easier. But if you *need/want* a const: `(declare-fun result1 () Int) (assert (= result1 (ite (> s1 s2) s1 s2)))`. Like that.